# Using grep --exclude-dir on OSX

Tags: bash, grep, filenames, macos

I am trying to find a file that contains the text "The default interactive shell". I am trying to use the following grep command to find it:

`grep -r --exclude-dir='/{var,Volumes,bin,cores,dev,sbin,tmp,usr}' "The default interactive shell" /`

however it still searches `/usr` as shown by this error message:

`grep: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied`

How can I perform a recursive grep and exclude multiple directories without writing multiple `--exclude-dir` options? The system is OSX 10.15.4.

Comment: Try removing the single-quotes around the list of directories. Without them, the shell will expand the brace expression to `--exclude-dir=/var --exclude-dir=/Volumes --exclude-dir=/bin ...` etc.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are excluding a directory with the literal name `/{var,Volumes,bin,cores,dev,sbin,tmp,usr}`.  This is due to the single quotes. When a brace expansion is quoted, it is no longer a brace expansion, just ordinary text.

To properly let the brace expansion expand, remove the quotes:

```
grep -R --exclude-dir=/{var,Volumes,bin,cores,dev,sbin,tmp,usr} \
    -F 'The default interactive shell' /
```

I've also added `-F` since you're searching with a string, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same thing ...

When my bash terminal in OSX Big Sur started, it gave this message ...

"The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit [https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050."](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.%22)

So I did a grep search looking for a file containing the words "The default interactive shell". I did not find such a file.

As it turned out, the message "The default interactive shell etc" is actually hard coded into bash.

hexdump -C /bin/bash yields ...

000775c0  6e 2f 7a 73 68 00 0a 54  68 65 20 64 65 66 61 75  |n/zsh..The defau|

000775d0  6c 74 20 69 6e 74 65 72  61 63 74 69 76 65 20 73  |lt interactive s|

000775e0  68 65 6c 6c 20 69 73 20  6e 6f 77 20 7a 73 68 2e  |hell is now zsh.|

(Note: My $BASH_VERSION is 3.2.57(1)-release)

(Note: There are many ASCII messages hard coded into bash.)

This warning can be silenced by putting the following line in your ~/.bash_profile
export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1

Ian James